# Is there any website like vocabulary.com , but for German?

Tags: learning, vocabulary

I search for a website to learn German words of intermediate and advanced level, preferably not with translation, but with explanation in German. Vocabulary.com is the perfect example of what do I need. (German-to-English translation will be of no use for me, because English isn't my native language)

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is [Das digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](http://www.dwds.de). After entering the search word, look especially in the upper left box for the definition.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Wortschatz](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/) bei the University of Leipzig. It is a corpora collection that automatically crawls online ressources and give example sentences.

They at the time of writing this have 26 Mio sentences and 425 Mio tokens.

Comment: In my opinion Wortschatz Leipzig provides many example sentences, it provides no explanation and looks therefore not like a satisfactory answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](http://easy-deutsch.de/deutsch-lernen-vokabeln/) vocabularies **categorized by subject** and explained in German or with examples ( the website offers the explanation in English sometimes too! ) with pictures *when needed*.

For example [here](http://easy-deutsch.de/vokabeln-das-wohnzimmer/) is vocabularies for living room

Answer (score 0):

There is also the web presence of [Duden](http://www.duden.de/definition) another often used dictionay in Germany. It may help you as well.

Edit: This web presence in only in german availibale, but that shouldn't be a problem for you.